# Why special characters like () "" : [] are often removed from data before training translation machine?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, machine-translation

I see that people often remove special characters like () "" : [] from data before training translation machine. Could you explain for me the benefits of doing so?

Comment: Without any context or example it's hard to explain anything. But here is an example: imagine I have a translation model which knows about individual words, and about words ordered in a sentence, and nothing else. Then anything which isn't a word must be removed before my model processes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date clean-up or pre-processing is performed so that algorithms could focus on important, linguistically meaningful "words" instead of "noise". See ["*Removing Special Characters*"](https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-building-text-cleanup-and-preprocessing-pipeline-eba4095245a0):

> Special characters, as you know, are non-alphanumeric characters.
> These characters are most often found in comments, references,
> currency numbers etc. These characters add no value to
> text-understanding and induce noise into algorithms.

Whenever this noise finds its way into a model, it can produce output at inference, that contains these unexpected (sequences of) characters, and even affect overall translations. It is a frequent case with brackets in Japanese translations.